# Unable to clear ModelState errors client side? Is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Obviously I am using  `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in my View to display any errors that may have occurred when the user posted to my controller.

However this is my scenario

- The user posts to the controller and `ModelState.IsValid = false;`
- `@Html.ValidationSummary()` displays my error message to the user.
- Now the user corrects the error and clicks the submit button.  
  However I want to clear that error message because I may present the user another option (client side script) prior to the post actually occurring.

I've tried various techniques for hiding the Validation Summary section to no avail.

```
function resetValidation() {

    $("form").data("valmsg-summary").hide();
    $(".field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
    $(".input-validation-error").addClass("input-validation-valid");
    $(".validation-summary-errors").addClass("validation-summary-valid");

    $(".field-validation-error").removeClass("field-validation-error");
    $(".input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error");
    $(".validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-errors");
};
```

This is the script of my Submit button.

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
        resetValidation();  // Trying to suppress/clear error messages

        var doPost = true;
        var p1 = $("#Field1").val();
        var p2 = $("#Field2").val();
        var p3 = $("#Field3").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/MyController/MyAction",
            data: { "param1": p1, "param2": p2, "param3": p3 },
            async: false
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data > 999)
            {
                // I then display a new set of fields for the user to answer 
                doPost = false;
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });

        return doPost;
    });
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?
Is it possible to clear the modelview errors client side?

Comment: `$(".validation-summary-errors").empty();` should remove the error messages

Comment: That seems to work!  ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke for the solution:

$(".validation-summary-errors").empty();